# can i use md5 hashed values inside $this->db->escape() in codeigniter,

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

when i tried to use md5 hashed values inside $this->db->escape() i'm getting error like below when i tried to fetch count of results
"Call to a member function num_rows() on bool"

my code

```
$hashedUniqueId= md5($uniqueId);
$query = "select * from my_table where uId_hash= '".$this->db->escape($hashedUniqueId)."' AND password= '".$this->db->escape($password)."' ";
$result = $this->db->query($query);
print_r($result->num_rows());
```

Comment: Hello Kasi, and welcome to the community.
As far as i see, the query looks fine from the syntax perspective (though i'm not sure about columns names and tables names).
I exclude the relation of `md5()` to the error, because the output of `md5()` is already a string,so there's nothing wrong here.
The error must be something else, can you provide more code and your table fields ?

Comment: @EyadMohammedOsama the thing is that when i remove this $this->db->escape() and run the query like $query = "select * from my_table where uId_hash= '".$hashedUniqueId."' AND password= '".$password."' "; this it's working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are making double escape as i see it. Remove the single quotes from $this->db->escape().

```
$query = "select * from my_table where uId_hash= ".$this->db->escape($hashedUniqueId)." AND password= ".$this->db->escape($password);
```

Or the better way is to set the variables in the $this->db->query($query);
This way codeigniter will escape it for you.

```
$hashedUniqueId= md5( $uniqueId );
$query = "select * from my_table where uId_hash= ? AND password= ?";
$result = $this->db->query( $query, array( $hashedUniqueId, $password ) );
print_r($result->num_rows());
```